# Why JPA @PreUpdate not call after @PostLoad in same Transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My Bean class is:

```
package com.abcfinancial.api.generalledger.fee.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Entity
@Table( name = "fee" )
@EntityListeners( FeeListner.class )
public class Fee
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column( name = "fee_id" )
    private UUID feeId;

    @Column( name = "accn_id" )
    private UUID accountId;

    @Column( Name = "fee_created" )
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column( name = "fee_deactivated" )
    private LocalDateTime deactivated;

    @Column( name = "fee_modified" )
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    @Column( name = "fm_key" )
    private String feeMode;

    @Column( name = "ft_key" )
    private String feeType;

    @Column( name = "ftt_key" )
    private String feeTransactionType;

    @Column( name = "fvt_key" )
    private String feeValueType;

    @Column( name = "fee_value" )
    private BigDecimal feeValue;

    @Transient
    private boolean active;

    @PostLoad
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void postLoad()
    {
        if( this.deactivated == null )
        {
            this.active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In above class i want to make active for fee by using `deactivated` variable. if Fee is deactivated then Fee is not active else vice versa.This concept work in case of Create, Delete and get Fee case but not working for update Fee.

In Update Fee we get Fee by id and update one variable in same Transaction.Below is my Update Fee code(service method):

```
@Transactional
public UpdateFeeVO updateFeeDetails( UpdateFeeRequestVO updateFeeVO, UUID feeId )
{
    Optional<Fee> feeOptional = feeRepository.getDetailsByFeeId( feeId );//After this line feeOptional.get().getActive() give true
    if( feeOptional.isPresent() )
    {
        //update some variable
        feeRepository.save( feeOptional.get() );
        log.trace( "Fee: {}",feeOptional.get() );// feeOptional.get().getActive() give false
    }
}
```

**I don't want to change in service file**

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if this helped you

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need that active variable and this postLoad Method.

Activated variable is not persisted anyway.

Just change or override your getter of isActive() to

```
public boolean isActive(){
   return deactivated == null || deactivated.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but motive of this question is to know the working of `PreUpdate` with `Transaction`.

Comment: You are using it in a wrong way: https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove

Comment: See my second answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in a wrong way. 
Use entitylisteners like this :
https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove